# Writing own iTunes IAP receipt validation server, unique data in receipt?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, receipt-validation

I'm trying to validate my own receipts for IAP. I'm facing a few problems regarding finding a constant data point which I can check for uniqueness.

The first problem is a large number of my receipts have `status: 0`
yet, the `in_app` field is an empty array. Meaning there are no `transaction_id, original_transaction_id`.

I've seen this question asked here and on Apple support forums but haven't seen any decisive or official answers on these types of receipts- are they valid, etc.

The 2nd problem is finding a unique data point. If we ignore the case of the empty `in_app` field, and only take care of receipts with `transaction_id`.

Is there any legitimate scenario where a `transaction_id` shows up twice? Or is that a verified fake receipt?

Comment: Use original transaction id. It's unique. Don't know about the lack of receipts in the array. Are you able to decrypt the receipt on the device? Does it have purchases there? I suspect you refreshed a receipt and it was empty of purchases-- ie, that Apple Id had made no purchases. What purchase types are you dealing with?

Comment: @ChrisPrince All types of purchases, once the purchase is completed I send the receipt to my own server for verification. The vast majority of receipts that get to my server have empty `in_app` array which is very odd.